# buttons resizing them selves?

Tags: java, user-interface

Me and a friend are trying to make an mp3 player with buttons in java, however once the first button is clicked it resizes all butttons on the second menu. 
Any information on how to keep the buttons from rezising would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import java.awt.event.*;
       import javax.swing.*;
       import java.awt.*;

   public class Player extends JFrame {


  class CustomPanel extends JPanel{     //create image
     public void paintComponent (Graphics painter){
        Image pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("playerBase.jpg");
        if(pic != null) painter.drawImage(pic, 0, 0, this);
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Player gui = new Player();
     gui.go();
  }

  public void go() {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("MP3 Player."); //Creates window.
     CustomPanel base = new CustomPanel(); //Makes the image into a panel.
     JButton button1 = new JButton("Artists");
     JButton button2 = new JButton("Genres");
     JButton button3 = new JButton("Songs");
     JButton button4 = new JButton("TEST");
     JButton button5 = new JButton("TEST");
     button1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
     button2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
     button3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
     button4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
     button5.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
     button1.addActionListener(new Button1Listener());
     button2.addActionListener(new Button2Listener());
     button3.addActionListener(new Button3Listener());
     button4.addActionListener(new Button4Listener());
     button5.addActionListener(new Button5Listener());


     base.add(button1);
     base.add(button2);


       base.add(button3);
         base.add(button4);
         base.add(button5);

         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
         frame.setSize(304, 360);
         frame.setResizable(false);
         frame.add(base);
         frame.setVisible(true);

         button1.setSize(280, 30);
         button1.setLocation(10,10);
         button1.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
         button1.setForeground(Color.white);
         button2.setSize(280, 30);
         button2.setLocation(10,40);
         button2.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
         button2.setForeground(Color.white);
         button3.setSize(280, 30);
         button3.setLocation(10,70);
         button3.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
         button3.setForeground(Color.white);
         button4.setSize(280, 30);
         button4.setLocation(10,100);
         button4.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
         button4.setForeground(Color.white);
         button5.setSize(280, 30);
         button5.setLocation(10,130);
         button5.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
         button5.setForeground(Color.white);

      }


   //These are the actions for the 5 buttons.
    //Need to get buttons straight once first button is clicked
      class Button1Listener implements ActionListener {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton) { 
               JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource(); 
               clickedButton.setSize(280, 30);
               clickedButton.setLocation(10,10);
               clickedButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
               clickedButton.setForeground(Color.white);



               String buttonText = clickedButton.getText(); 
               if (buttonText.equals("Artists")) { 
                  System.out.println("Artists");
                  clickedButton.setText("Back");

               } 
               else if (buttonText.equals("Back")) { 
                  System.out.println("Back");
               } 
            } 
         } 
      }
   //these are just place holders for the other buttons.
      class Button2Listener implements ActionListener {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Genres");
         }
      }

      class Button3Listener implements ActionListener {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Songs");
         }
      }

      class Button4Listener implements ActionListener {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("TEST");
         }
      }

      class Button5Listener implements ActionListener {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("TEST");
         }
      }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the layout Manager to null on your `CustomPanel base`.

```
base.setLayout(null);
```

If you want to force the size and location of your components (using setBounds()), then you need to remove the layout manager.

However, LayoutManagers provide better UI experience across different platforms as they will adapt to differences. LayoutManager's perform the sizing and positionning of the components based on preferredSize and constraints. If you have never used them or heard from them, you should really consider looking into them: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: @LucasRibeiro You're welcome. I edited my answer, because you should maybe consider using a layout manager, but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

well, I didn't see a menu code. However, by default, the Layout manager for `Panel` is Flow Layout. Since you did not specify any layout, `Flow Layout` is assumed, and any sizing you specify will largely be ignored.

So, as Guillaume suggests, set it to null, so you can position things absolutely. Or use more complex layouts depending on your needs. Have a look at how to use layout managers in the [swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). `GridBagLayout` is the most complex (difficult to use), unless you use some sort of gui builder. Other candidates are `BorderLayout`, `GridLayout` among others. Read through the examples to see which one fits your case.